# Como encontrar el path de una carpeta en android?

Tags: android, aws, rutas, keystore

Estoy usando el SDW de AWS (Amazon Web Services) para enviar datos al IOT de AWS con mi aplicación. En esta aplicación primero tengo que conectarme con AWS IOT.
El método para conectarme necesita un keyStore. Tengo este keyStore y lo tengo guardado en una carpeta en mi móvil.

El problema es que para acceder a este archivo lo he de hacer mediante la referencia por un string y el nombre del keyStore. (`keyStorePath` es un string al igual que el nombre).

```
if (AWSIotKeystoreHelper.isKeystorePresent(keystorePath, KEYSTORE_NAME)) {
```

Con este método simplemente compruebo que esté el keyStore, pero siempre devuelve falso ya que no referencio bien el path ya que no se dónde empieza (root) y no sé cómo referenciar la carpeta.

Una solución que he pensado sería cargar el keyStore en la aplicación en una carpeta, pero tampoco sé cómo conseguir el path ya que empieza desde "c/users/..." que es mi equipo.

Answer (score 1):

> Tengo este keyStore y lo tengo guardado en una carpeta en mi móvil.

Lo correcto para obtener la ruta del keystore es usar :

```
 String keystorePath = getFilesDir().getPath();
```

para obtener la ruta que es generalmente:

```
 ../data/data/<com.dominio.myapplication>/files
```

---

En cuanto al nombre del keystore simplemente definelo en la variable estatica:

`private static final String KEYSTORE_NAME = "awskeystore";`

Revisa un ejemplo de AWS:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples